# indexOf in array returns -1 instead of index number

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing, indexof

When I pass 'orderOfPlanets' into my each(){}; function, I expect to get the name of the planet and the corresponding index number, however I get -1 each time. Why is this?

```
var mostEvil = {
    Cthulhu: "Most evil",
    Dracula: "Fairly evil",
    Voldermort: "Pretty damn evil",
    Sauron: "Ridiculously evil"
};

var orderOfPlanets = ["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars"];

function each(input, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < orderOfPlanets.length; i++) {
            var name = orderOfPlanets[i];
            var val = orderOfPlanets.indexOf(i);
            callback(val, name);
        }
    } else if (typeof input == "object") {
        for (var key in input) {
            var name = key;
            var val = input[key];
            callback(val, name);
        }
    }
}

each(orderOfPlanets, function(val, name) {
    console.log("The value of " + name + " is " + val);
});
```

The value of Mercury is 0
The value of Venus is 1
The value of Earth is 2
The value of Mars is 3

Comment: You pass an index to `indexOf`. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: You already have `i`; `indexOf` is redundant...

Comment: `indexOf` looks for elements within an array and returns the index. So for example `orderOfPlanets.indexOf('Venus')` will return 1. You're passing i, which is the index, not the name. What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: Arrays have a built-in `.forEach()` method. And `Object.keys()`, `Obejct.values()` and `Object.entries()` turn an object into various flavors of arrays. So if you so desire, you can use `orderOfPlanets .forEach()` and `Object.entries( mostEvil ).forEach()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the `indexOf` of the name not i (the index)

```js
var mostEvil = {
    Cthulhu: "Most evil",
    Dracula: "Fairly evil",
    Voldermort: "Pretty damn evil",
    Sauron: "Ridiculously evil"
};

var orderOfPlanets = ["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars"];

function each(input, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < orderOfPlanets.length; i++) {
            var name = orderOfPlanets[i];
            //var val = orderOfPlanets.indexOf(i);
            var val = orderOfPlanets.indexOf(name);
            callback(val, name);
        }
    } else if (typeof input == "object") {
        for (var key in input) {
            var name = key;
            var val = input[key];
            callback(val, name);
        }
    }
}

each(orderOfPlanets, function(val, name) {
    console.log("The value of " + name + " is " + val);
});
```

Just as effective is returning `i`

```js
var mostEvil = {
    Cthulhu: "Most evil",
    Dracula: "Fairly evil",
    Voldermort: "Pretty damn evil",
    Sauron: "Ridiculously evil"
};

var orderOfPlanets = ["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars"];

function each(input, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < orderOfPlanets.length; i++) {
            var name = orderOfPlanets[i];
            //var val = orderOfPlanets.indexOf(i);
            var val = i;
            callback(val, name);
        }
    } else if (typeof input == "object") {
        for (var key in input) {
            var name = key;
            var val = input[key];
            callback(val, name);
        }
    }
}

each(orderOfPlanets, function(val, name) {
    console.log("The value of " + name + " is " + val);
});
```

Comment: Yeah but `var val = orderOfPlanets.indexOf(name);` just returns `i`, which he already has. It's completely redundant.

Comment: This answer is still correct though; the question was "Why is indexOf returning -1 all the time", and demonstrating the correct usage of `indexOf(name)` answers that. The redundancy is a secondary effect.